# site loading time increased due to plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

in order to improve the bounce rate of my wordpress blog http://palchoice.com/ i have installed the upprev plugin. it do helped me to reduce site bounce rate but it also increased my site loading time.
i really want to use this plugin but i have to de-install it due to increased site loading time.
can anyone help me with this plugin setting so that i can use it on my blog with no adverse effect on my site loading speed?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are having high bounce rate that means your site visitors are not getting what they are looking for or your content is too short. Best thing to do is installing plugins which suggests related posts to the visitor such as **Yet Another Related Posts Plugin** so that he will spend much more time in your site.

Comment: my question is specifically concerned about how to use newyork style upprev plugin without sacrificing page loading speed, since this plugin increase the time to load your website. i am interested in plugin setting...